# Facebook Open Graph share issue

Tags: facebook, graph

I have Facebook share button on my Wordpress site. I have the open graph call in my `functions.php`. The problem I'm having is when you press the share button below a single post you get the meta description of the site from `header.php` along with a random image posted to Facebook.

When you use twitter which I have linked to my Facebook page you all the meta info along with the correct image for that particular post the same with a Facebook linked Pinterest account.

I've used the Facebook developer tool scraped various post URL and the all came back with the correct meta info and image error free. Can anyone explain this issue to me.

Comment: Give us an example URL demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was.
Posting solution in case anyone might come across the same problem.

add: `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` to the `data-href`= URL:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-layout="button"></div>
```

oppose to:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="YOUR SITE URL" data-layout="button"></div>
```

This will load all pertinent info into the Facebook Iframe for Facebook Posting.